# why the following Jquery Ajax Call executes just once?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have the following script in my ASP.NET MVC Project :

```
$(function () {

var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
    var $form = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
        var $newHtml = $(data);
        $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
    });

    return false;
};

$("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
});
```

why this fonction executes just once ? this function is for updating a list of objects , here is the form on the razor view :

```
<form  method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")" data-otf-ajax ="true" 
data-otf-target="#RestaurantList">
<input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
<input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />
</form>

<div id="RestaurantList">
@Html.Partial("_Restaurants")
</div>
```

Comment: Put the javascript code outside of the `RestaurantList` div....maybe it gots overwritten by the ajax call.

Comment: try using input type `button` and execute the above function using Jquery's `click(function)` and do let me know..

Comment: The javascript code is in seperate file , i bundled it with the jquery scripts (  @Scripts.Render .. )

Comment: when i put alert in the function , it shows the result evey time i submit , but the update in the view will be done just the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not executed only once. The problem is that when your handler is executed the first time, you are replacing the element whose id is `RestaurantList` with the HTML code returned by the ajax call.

So, the next time it is executed, this line

```
var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
```

won't have the expected behaviour (because there is no element with the id `RestaurantList` in your document anymore.

Try updating the content of your `RestaurantList` element with the .html() method instead of replaceWith() :

```
$.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
        var $newHtml = $(data);
        $target.html($newHtml);
    });
```

That way, your element still has the same id. And the next execution of your handler should work fine.